# Namespace goes wrong during serializations

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a problem with xml serialization in c#.

I have an xml structured like this:

```
<foo xmlns:"namespace">
 <bar xmlns:"othernamespace">
  <bars></bars>
 </bar>
</foo>
```

I have to deserialize this xml, that works fine, but when I serialize the class I get an xml structured like this:

```
<foo xmlns:"namespace">
 <bar>
  <bars xmlns:"othernamespace"></bars>
 </bar>
</foo>
```

Even though i specify the namespace of bar like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="othernamespace")]
public class Bar(){...}
```

I need the xml to have the very same structure as it was before deserialization, but I just can't figure out what I did wrong, or how can I set up the attributes during serialization.

Comment: Can you post your model types?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't.